# Removal of child from aggregate root and database persistence

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

(This is possibly a duplicate, but I didn't find any satisfactory answers in the other questions I've read.)

I need some guidance on how removal of child entities of an aggregate root can be propagated to the database layer. I've though/read about a couple of different ways to handle it:

1. Keep removed children i separate collection. Let the repository remove all items in the collection on save.
2. Call some kind of data mapping layer or repository directly.
3. Execute some type of delegate/event that a repository/UoW may provide/listen to.
4. Do nothing. Let the Unit of work or repository compare the whole aggregate root with a "non-dirty" copy.

It's worth noting that my real aggregate root implementation contains multiple collections of children that possibly could be removed.

For the sake of clarity, here is a simple example:

```
public class AggregateRoot 
{
    private List<ChildEntity> _children;
    public IEnumerable<ChildEntity> Children 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _children; 
        } 
    }
    public void RemoveChild(ChildEntity child)
    {
        _children.Remove(child);

        // What to do here?

        // Option 1: Keep removed children i separate collection. Let 
        // the repository remove them on save.
        RemovedChildren.Add(child);

        // Option 2: Call some kind of data mapping layer or repository directly
        _childRepository.Delete(child);

        // Option 3: Execute some type of delegate/event that a repository 
        // may provide/listen to.
        _onChildRemoved(this, child);

        // Option 4: Do nothing. Let the Unit of work or repository compare 
        // the whole aggregate root with a "non-dirty" copy.

    }
}
```

Options 1 and 2 are not very elegant I think.

Option 4 is nice as I don't have to implent any logic inside the aggregate root, but as my real implementation is quite large, I would have to compare a lot of properties and collections.

I tend to favor option 3. The problem with it is that it potentially may require a lot of delegates/events. Maybe I could implement a generic delegate/event though.

This must be a fairly common problem, but I've seen surprisingly few examples of this. How would you handle this problem?

Comment: If you have a unit of work, you may have a repository that is scoped within the UoW lifespan. Record the removal in the repository (where it should be) and on commit of the UoW, the repository can review its removed items and remove them as needed from the underlying source. If this is something like EF, then it is handled for you.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth How would you notify the repository of the removal then? (I'm not using EF by the way)

Comment: When you remove the item you can raise a domain event so that ambient change tracking can catch it for later reference, or you can promote the idea in your domain model itself (that an item can be removed and so not usable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
I guess that in your business there isn't such concept as RemovedChildren, so aggregate shouldn't contain such collection in my opinion. Please mind that sometimes there might be such concept like ChildrenHistory, HistoricalChildren

Option 2:
I have read plenty of times that aggregate shouldn't use repository, and aggregate shouldn't have any services injected. However you can use double dispatch pattern and provide method signature like:

```
public void RemoveChild(ChildEntity child, IChildRepository repository)
{
    // check conditions, business logic etc
    // remove using repository
```

However it forces caller to supply repository which might be hard to achieve in some cases

Option 3:
I didn't use events for this purpose before. But it seems pretty ok for me. You can use event bus to notify interested repositories about entity deletion.

Option 4:
In my opinion this is best way, UoW should handle item deletion. You can mark your entity as removed either by setting some kind of flag on them or by setting their ParentId to 0 (that is what EF does under the hood). On commit you can inspect all objects loaded into memory and remove those that are marked for deletion. This forces us to write least infrastructure code in domain layer, however we need to write additional code in our UoW for deleting orphaned children.

Comment: Thanks for an answer that broadened my thoughts about this issue. 

I actually went with option 3 and let the aggregate root's repository delete any children as there was no repositories implemented for the child entities. 

I will probably go with option 4 the next time, but it seems to require a bit more general implementation of entity deletion in the UoW.

One option could be a combination of option 3 and 4 though - raise an event that the UoW listens to...